# distincto vs. fd/distinct in core.logic

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

What is the advantage of using `fd/distinct` in cases where the elements will be in a finite domain instead of `distincto`?

The following all return `([0 1] [1 0])`.

```
;;; With distincto
(run* [q]
  (fresh [x y]
    (fd/in x y (fd/interval 1))
      (distincto [x y])
      (== q [x y])))

;;; With fd/distinct
(run* [q]
  (fresh [x y]
    (fd/in x y (fd/interval 1))
      (fd/distinct [x y])
      (== q [x y])))

;;; Without fd at all. 
(let [interval [0 1]]
  (run* [q]
    (fresh [x y]
      (membero x interval)
      (membero y interval)
      (distincto [x y])
      (== q [x y]))))
```

Notably, although it appears you may use `distincto` in any place where you may use `fd/distinct` (but not the other way around), the same cannot be said for `membero` and `fd/in`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fd/distinct` is much more highly optimized than `distincto` which must receive any kind of value. `fd/distinct` under the hood deals with efficient representations of constrained variables all at once using sets, `distincto` uses the disequality operator `!=` in a pretty simple manner.